# why is MPI_Scatterv 's recvcount a fixed int and sendcount an array?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, scatterview

this is the synopsis of `MPI_Scatterv()`

```
    int MPI_Scatterv(const void *sendbuf, const int *sendcounts, const int *displs,
             MPI_Datatype sendtype, void *recvbuf, int recvcount,
             MPI_Datatype recvtype,
             int root, MPI_Comm comm)
```

I cannot seem to understand how this works. IF `MPI_Scatterv()` is sending different chunk sized elements that are stored in `*sendcounts` then why is `recvcount` a fixed integer and not an array of chunk sizes as well?

and also since its a fixed integer, what should the value be. should it be equal to the maximum value of the `sendcount` array? For example if I have

```
   int sendcount[4] = {1,5,10,8};
```

should `recvcount` be equal to 10 ?

Comment: Might be useful for you to read at this QA in SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165337/mpis-scatterv-operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendcounts` specify the actual chunk sizes to be sent. `recvcount` specifies the size of the local receive buffer, e.g. `recvcount=sendcounts[rank]`.

In detail it is a bit more complex: The size of the receive buffer needs to be at least large enough to store the chunk for a given rank. If different types are involved the type extents also matter.